# How to optimise this TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, optimization

This query takes about `01:30` to run:

```
select DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t1.[OccurredOn]))
       , count(t2.UserId)
       , count(*) - count(t2.UserId)
from Events t1
left join (select c.UserId, min(c.OccurredOn) FirstOccurred
           from Events c
           where [OccurredOn] between @start and @end
           group by c.UserId) t2 on t1.OccurredOn = t2.FirstOccurred and t1.UserId = t2.UserId
where t1.EventType = @eventType
    and t1.[OccurredOn] between @start and @end
group by DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t1.[OccurredOn]))
order by DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t1.[OccurredOn]))
```

If I remove the `WHERE` clause from the subquery, it runs instantly.

Running the subquery by itself, with the `WHERE` takes < 1s

If I `SELECT` the subquery into a table variable first, and join to that, the whole query runs in 19s.

The `Events` Table looks like:

```
[Events](
    [EventType] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [OccurredOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)
```

I've got the following `primary, nonclustered, nounique` indexes:

- EventType
- UserId
- OccurredOn

Here's the execution plan

[image]

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Two things:

1. What's happening to make this slow?
2. How do I speed it up?

Comment: Please **SHOW US** the table structure, columns and their datatypes, tell us what indexes you have...  - also what **VERSION** of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: good point, meant to add add. standby

Comment: And have you looked at the execution plan? What does it show?

Comment: Are you sure your query even works? Your sub-query returns a column named `FirstOccured` which is technically a lie because the where clause means it's the first AFTER `@start`. Furthermore, one would expect FirstOccurred to be the first occurrence of an event. But this is not at all the case. So, if your sub-query is already misleading about what it's supposed to do - how can you be sure the rest is correct? Perhaps it would be best if you explain what the query is supposed to do - I suspect a complete rewrite is in order, not just some optimisation.

Comment: I've told you that you have some serious problems with the way you've written your query. I can also tell you that you almost certainly have the wrong indexes because your explanation of the indexes doesn't make any sense (primary indexes that are not unique?? multiple primary indexes??). The point is, if you can't be bothered to explain what your query is supposed to do - how do expect anyone to help you rewrite it and fix your problem? - This is not an answerable question!

Answer (score 1):

Your query is slow as your ordering depends on on-the-fly computation( `DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t1.[OccurredOn]))` ), Sql Server can't utilize an index on on-the-fly computation.

Postgresql has [index on expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html), with Postgresql, you can basically persist the result of an expression to an actual column(behind-the-scene column) for you, so when the time comes you need to sort on that expression, Postgresql can use index on that expression.

The closest analogous feature in Sql Server is persisted formula.

You can easily verify the feature by this sample query:

```
create table PersonX
(
Lastname varchar(50) not null,
Firstname varchar(50) not null
);

create table PersonY
(
Lastname varchar(50) not null,
Firstname varchar(50) not null
);


alter table PersonX add Fullname as Lastname + ', ' + Firstname PERSISTED;    
create index ix_PersonX on PersonX(Fullname);

declare @i int = 0;

while @i < 10000 begin
    insert into PersonX(Lastname,Firstname) values('Lennon','John');
    insert into PersonY(Lastname,Firstname) values('Lennon','John');
    set @i = @i + 1;
end;


select top 1000 Lastname, Firstname
from PersonX
order by Fullname;


select top 1000 Lastname, Firstname
from PersonY
order by Lastname + ', ' + Firstname;
```

Doing an order on fullname on PersonX is faster than PersonY. PersonX has a query cost of 32% only, while PersonY is 68%

To solve your query's performance, do these:

```
alter table Events 
    add OccurenceGroup as 
        DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [OccurredOn])) PERSISTED

create index ix_Events on Events(OccurenceGroup);
```

Then do grouping and ordering on OccurenceGroup.

---

By the way, did you add an index on OccuredOn, and also on EventType?

Answer (score 1):

You could try replacing `LEFT JOIN` with `LEFT MERGE JOIN` so that the derived table `t2` is just calculated once rather than recalculating the `MIN` possibly many times for each user.

You could also rewrite this using ranking functions as below. It may be cheaper. You would need to test these ideas against your data and indexes.

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY OccurredOn) AS Rnk
FROM Events
WHERE [OccurredOn] BETWEEN @start AND @end
)
SELECT Dateadd(dd, 0, Datediff(dd, 0, OccurredOn)),
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Rnk =1 THEN 1 END),
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Rnk >1 THEN 1 END)
FROM T
WHERE EventType = @eventType      
GROUP BY Dateadd(dd, 0, Datediff(dd, 0, OccurredOn)) 
ORDER BY Dateadd(dd, 0, Datediff(dd, 0, OccurredOn))
```